# Get DateTime of the next nth day of the month

Tags: c#, datetime

If given a date and a variable n, how can I calculate the DateTime for which the day of the month will be the nth Date?

For example, Today is the 17th of June.
I would like a function that when provided 15 would return the DateTime for July 15.

A few more examples:

- Today is Feb. 26: Function would return March 30 when provided 30.
- Today is Dec. 28. Function would return Jan 4 when provided 4.
- Today is Feb. 28. Function would return March 29 when provided 29, unless it was a leap year, in which case it would return Feb 29.

Comment: Why next 15th day after 15th of January should be 30th of March? o.O

Comment: it should be 30/01 right?

Comment: @Sajeetharan That's depends on what OP wants for 15th day of months. It can be the same, of it can be the 15th of the next month.It won't be 30th day for any case, at least I hope

Comment: Incomplete functional spec.  You must describe what is supposed to happen when asking for, say, the 29th in February or the 31st in March.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Perhaps change the title to "Get next DateTime for the nth day of the month" or something along those lines, to make it easier to find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do?

```
private DateTime GetNextDate(DateTime dt, int DesiredDay)
{
    if (DesiredDay >= 1 && DesiredDay <= 31)
    {
        do
        {
            dt = dt.AddDays(1);
        } while (dt.Day != DesiredDay);
        return dt.Date;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }     
}
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer, but would worry about lengthy computation time.

Comment: +1 checking ~60 days is probably better performance than catching one exception as in my answer.  Just need to guard against the infinite loop from invalid input and this answer is good to go.

Comment: @Amy B, after 3 years, this code was finally revised to your exact solution. Much more readable and more easily understood.

Answer (score 2):

After many, many edits, corrections and re-writes, here is my final answer:

The method that follows returns a a `DateTime` representing the next time the day of number `day` comes up in the calendar. It does so using an iterative approach, and is written in the form of an extension method for `DateTime` objects, and thus isn't bound to today's date but will work with any date.

The code executes the following steps to get the desired result:

1. Ensure that the day number provided is valid (greater than zero and smaller than 32).
2. Enter into a while loop that keeps going forever (until we break).
3. Check if `cDate`'s month works (the day must not have passed, and the month must have enough days in it).

   - If so, return.
   - If not, increase the month by one, set the day to one, set `includeToday` to true so that the first day of the new month is included, and execute the loop again.

The code:

```
static DateTime GetNextDate3(this DateTime cDate, int day, bool includeToday = false)
{
    // Make sure provided day is valid
    if (day > 0 && day <= 31)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // See if day has passed in current month or is not contained in it at all
            if ((includeToday && day > cDate.Day || (includeToday && day >= cDate.Day)) && day <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(cDate.Year, cDate.Month))
            {
                // If so, break and return
                break;
            }

            // Advance month by one and set day to one
            // FIXED BUG HERE (note the order of the two calls)
            cDate = cDate.AddDays(1 - cDate.Day).AddMonths(1);

            // Set includeToday to true so that the first of every month is taken into account
            includeToday = true;
        }
        // Return if the cDate's month contains day and it hasn't passed
        return new DateTime(cDate.Year, cDate.Month, day);
    }

    // Day provided wasn't a valid one
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("day", "Day isn't valid");
}
```

Comment: And when you put them in extensions methods for DateTime it would be more flexible and not tight bound to Today

Comment: Re-wrote everything, this time with a clear head. @DavidB thanks for the feedback, but turns out the method wasn't necessary.

Comment: @Sty, THANK YOU! I actually rewrote your pre-edit solution about 3 hours ago into a single function.  However, I will be using the iterative version that you currently have posted above. Thank you! I will need to go back and Unit Test this solution and will mark it as answer as soon as I conform it's accuracy and precision.

Comment: `cDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(1 - cDate.Day)` ... This operation on 2017-01-31 yields 2017-01-29.  I recommend setting the day before incrementing the month.

Comment: @W.Scott Check out the bugfixed version. I realized that due to the way the `if` was written. the first day of the month was never taken into account. With this new version I added an `includeToday` parameter which is force-set to true after the first loop execution. I also fixed `cDate.AddDays().AddMonths();`, per David.B's recommendation.

Comment: Need to set it to public

Answer (score 1):

The spec is a little bit unclear about to do when today is the dayOfMonth. I assumed it was it to return the same. Otherwise it would just be to change to <= today.Day

```
public DateTime FindNextDate(int dayOfMonth, DateTime today)
{
    var nextMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1).AddMonths(1);
    if(dayOfMonth < today.Day){ 
      nextMonth = nextMonth.AddMonths(1);
    }
    while(nextMonth.AddDays(-1).Day < dayOfMonth){
       nextMonth = nextMonth.AddMonths(1);
    }
    var month = nextMonth.AddMonths(-1);
    return new DateTime(month.Year, month.Month, dayOfMonth);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this thread today while trying to figure out this same problem.

From my testing, the following seems to work well and the loop only needs two goes (I think? Maybe 3 max(?)) to get to the answer:

```
public static DateTime GetNearestSpecificDay(DateTime start, int dayNum)
{
    if (dayNum >= 1 && dayNum <= 31)
    {
        DateTime result = start;
        while (result.Day != dayNum)
            result = dayNum > result.Day ? result.AddDays(dayNum - result.Day) : new DateTime(result.Month == 12 ? result.Year + 1 : result.Year, (result.Month % 12) + 1, 1);
        return result;
    }
    else
        return DateTime.Today;
}
```

---

Edit: As requested, here's a less compact version that walks through the logic step by step. I've also updated the original code to account for a required year change when we reach December.

```
public static DateTime GetNearestSpecificDay(DateTime start, int dayNum)
{
    // Check if target day is valid in the Gregorian calendar
    if (dayNum >= 1 && dayNum <= 31)
    {
        // Declare a variable which will hold our result & temporary results
        DateTime result = start;

        // While the current result's day is not the desired day
        while (result.Day != dayNum)
        {
            // If the desired day is greater than the current day
            if (dayNum > result.Day)
            {
                // Add the difference to try and skip to the target day (if we can, if the current month does not have enough days, we will be pushed into the next month and repeat)
                result = result.AddDays(dayNum - result.Day);
            }
            // Else, get the first day of the next month, then try the first step again (which should get us where we want to be)
            else
            {
                // If the desired day is less than the current result day, it means our result day must be in the next month (it obviously can't be in the current)
                // Get the next month by adding 1 to the current month mod 12 (so when we hit december, we go to january instead of trying to use a not real 13th month)
                // If result.Month is November, 11%12 = 11; 11 + 1 = 12, which rolls us into December
                // If result.Month is December, 12%12 = 0; 0 + 1 = 1, which rolls us into January
                var month = (result.Month % 12) + 1;

                // Get current/next year.
                // Since we are adding 1 to the current month, we can assume if the previous month was 12 that we must be entering into January of next year
                // Another way to do this would be to check if the new month is 1. It accomplishes the same thing but I chose 12 since it doesn't require an extra variable in the original code.
                // Below can be translated as "If last result month is 12, use current year + 1, else, use current year"
                var year = result.Month == 12 ? result.Year + 1 : result.Year;

                // Set result to the start of the next month in the current/next year
                result = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
            }
        }

        // Return result
        return result;
    }
    else
        // If our desired day is invalid, just return Today. This can be an exception or something as well, just using Today fit my use case better.
        return DateTime.Today;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Maybe you can explain the logic a bit more.

Comment: @GertArnold No problem. Updated the post to fix an issue & added a broken up version of the code with step-by-step comments on what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Fun little puzzle.  I generated 100 DateTimes which represent the starting day of each month, then checked each month to see if it had the date we want.  It's lazy so we stop when we find a good one.

```
public DateTime FindNextDate(int dayOfMonth, DateTime today)
{
  DateTime yesterday = today.AddDays(-1);
  DateTime currentMonthStart = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
  var query = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
    .Select(i => currentMonthStart.AddMonths(i))
    .Select(monthStart => MakeDateOrDefault(
      monthStart.Year, monthStart.Month, dayOfMonth,
      yesterday)
    .Where(date => today <= date)
    .Take(1);

  List<DateTime> results = query.ToList();
  if (!results.Any())
  {
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(dayOfMonth))
  }
  return results.Single();
}

public DateTime MakeDateOrDefault(
  int year, int month, int dayOfMonth,
  DateTime defaultDate)
{
  try
  {
    return new DateTime(year, month, dayOfMonth);
  }
  catch
  {
    return defaultDate;
  }
}
```